# Dynamic UITableView Datasource inside of Static UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There's probably a better way to do this, but I've been googling all day and can't find a solution to my specific problem:

I have a static TableView which displays a fair amount of information and includes a text entry portion to add values to a dynamic TableView nested in one of the cells of the parent static TableView.

To do this, I have a subclass of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate inside of my UITableViewController which will control what is displayed in the nested TableView.  I have an outlet to the nested table:

```
@IBOutlet weak var validatedCardsTable: UITableView!
```

In my `viewDidLoad` have:

```
let dataSource = ValidatedCardsDataSource(tableView: self.validatedCardsTable)
self.validatedCardsTable.dataSource = dataSource
self.validatedCardsTable.delegate = dataSource
```

and my subclass looks like this:

```
class ValidatedCardsDataSource :NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView:UITableView

    init(tableView : UITableView) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        super.init()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Title of Row: #\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the nested TableView loads the appropriate "Title of Row" text that I am setting in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (although the tableview isn't resizing, another issue altogether I'm sure).  However, when I press down on the TableView anywhere, a label I have designated "A Label" in the cell prototype in my storyboard shows on the cell as well, and then when I release the press, all formatting disappears and the cell reverts back to default state.  I'm assuming that I'm not fully hooking something up somewhere, but any help you can give in tracking down what I'm doing wrong, or suggesting a better way to handle this would be much appreciated! Screenshots below:

Prototype Cell:

[image: Prototype Cell]

What shows on load:

[image: loaded]

What shows on touch down:

[image: loaded]

What shows on touch up:

[image: loaded]

Comment: Maybe you should use sections! So you would have section headers (right now you have static cells) and only one section would have rows (which would change dynamically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimentation I was able to figure it out! Looking back it seems obvious, but I was doing some weird circular referencing ridiculousness when I instantiated my datasource.  I dropped out the `init` function, and the reference to the tableView argument I was using in my dataSource subclass.  This is what my dataSource class looks like now:

```
let dataSource = ValidatedCardsDataSource()
self.validatedCardsTable.dataSource = dataSource
self.validatedCardsTable.delegate = dataSource
```

```
class ValidatedCardsDataSource :NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var selectedRow = 0
    let rowCount = 10

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Title of Row: #\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now I just have to figure out my constraints...  Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Override your cell method "touchesBegan:withEvent: / touchesEnded:withEvent:/touchesCancelled:withEvent:"
When cell is touched down/upinside/upoutside, change UI style.